# Isolated Storage on Windows 8 (one by one)

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, isolatedstorage

I'm porting my game "Bustin' Jieber" on Windows Phone to Windows 8, and I have to do a isolated storage-like system to hold the settings, records and the money. I'm using this on windows phone:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings iosystem = IsolatedStorageSetting.ApplicationSettings;
```

and for example the money system;

```
iosystem["bjc"] = (int.Parse(iosystem["bjc"].ToString()) + (points * int.Parse(iosystem["pointduplication"].ToString())));
```

How can I implement this into my code? Please give me a usable code (with namespaces or so) ! Thanks! also, app is c#...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700361.aspx)

**Sample Code:**

Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

// Create a simple setting

localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"] = "Hello Windows";

// Read data from a simple setting

Object value = localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"];

if (value == null)
{
    // No data
}
else
{
    // Access data in value
}

// Delete a simple setting

localSettings.Values.Remove("exampleSetting");
```

& here is relevant post from [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/aff9982c-7ee6-4e96-8c79-e76c7bce6470/isolated-storage-for-metro-apps)

Apart from this you can try this from [CodePlex](https://isolatedstoragew8.codeplex.com/) [I didn't tried this before]

Answer (score 0):

By said by kumar, you can use ApplicationData stuff, but let me show you an easier version based on kumar's answer:

```
Windows.Foundation.Collections.IPropertySet setting = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values;
```

and just replace localsettings.Values (on kumar's answer) to setting. Good luck people :)